# ComboBox with entered text filtering - SAP UI5

Tags: sapui5

I have had a select control where I could select from  user names. Now I want to convert that select into combo box so I can give the user ability to enter text as well. The values populated in the combo box are in text property as {FirstName}, {LastName}. I do not want to use additional text as it shows at end of the row wih lot of space in between. My issue with Combo box is :

Values get populated but how do I filter? There is already some logic that is written on change method. I want to do custom filtering on the values. For example: If I write "P" it should show all the values that have P in the text (First name and last name). Where to write filter function? Also I found custom filtering code in demokit, I want to use it - but when I use it in inti method under delegate, I get error - this.get....setfilterfunction().. is not a function

View.xml

```
<ComboBox items= "{path:'items>/name'}" id="A"
  selectedKey="{item>/Header/Name}" change="nameSelected">
<core:ListItem key="{order>NameID}" text="{order>LastName} ,{order>FirstName}"/>
 </ComboBox>
```

Controller.js

```
_initializeData: function () {
var name = this.getView().byId("A");
 name.addEventDelegate({
      onAfterRendering: function() {
        this.getView().byId("A").setFilterFunction(function(sTerm, oItem) {
           return oItem.getText().match(new RegExp(sTerm, "i")) || 
                  oItem.getKey().match(new RegExp(sTerm, "i"));
        });
       }
      }, 

    nameSelected: function () {
     ......some logic processing..
   }
```

Comment: On suggestion would be to use SearchField : https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/sdk/#/sample/sap.m.sample.SearchFieldSuggestions/preview


If I see the issue in the meantime, will reply

Comment: could you not create a derived field (either as part of you model from the backend or on receipt of the model from the server?) i.e. fullname = LastName + ", " + FirstName?

Answer (score 0):

You have to bind this in your function. I guess.
Can you access  this.getView().byId("A") , when you put a break point in the onAfterRendering part ?

Try this solution: You are not working in the right scope.

```
 _initializeData: function () {

                var name = this.getView().byId("A");
                name.addEventDelegate({
                    onAfterRendering: this.setFilter.bind(this) });
            },


            setFilter: function() {
                this.getView().byId("A").setFilterFunction(function(sTerm, oItem) {
                    return oItem.getText().match(new RegExp(sTerm, "i")) ||
                        oItem.getKey().match(new RegExp(sTerm, "i"));
                });
            },
```

Comment: no I am not able to access this.getView() in onAfterRendering. Even after I bind(this), still cannot access. Why so and how to fix it? I saw this code in demo kit

Comment: Corrected my answer. Try it. Now you should be able to access this.getView().byId("A")

Comment: I still get error for this.getView().....setFilterFunction() is not a function. In my index.html the src version is 1.52.4 do you think that version does not  have that filterfunction, so it throws error?  I just want to filter values based on text entered by user like autosuggestion, is there a way using combo box only?

Comment: Please post your complete controller.